# can't access/log in ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, login

ironically,i was trying to make a backup for ubuntu by copying the whole drive,i have win10 beside ubuntu so i thought maybe i can copy the drive directly instead of using gparted with a flashdrive so i opened 'create and format hard disk partitions',and i remembered win can't see ex4 format.closed,restarted can't access ubuntu.the error image below

also before that i scanned an external hard drive for error and it required a restart during which a saw he quickly scanned other partitions.

[image]

[image: alt ctrl del]

Comment: Well I managed to identify the problem and a kind of solution,the problem is a partition of type ntfs with mount options defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0.     I just comment this line in fstab and everything worked except I no longer have the auto mount option.I think the problem with win 10 .how to do chkdsk /f on this particular partition.also I have another partition with the same mount options but has fat32 type,and both partitions exist on another hdd